# layout_width=match_parent, and layout_height=the same as width

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically, I want it to be a square that fills the screen horizontally. But what to specify for the height? I used FrameLayout as an example, but it may be any view.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ConstraintLayout, you can specify the DimensionRatio of the View with app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

(In ConstraintLayout you don't use match_parent, but you can use 0dp, which is equivalent to match_constraint, and if you set the  horizontal constraints to parent, it matches the parents width)

Answer (score 1):

So, its impossible to do only using the layout.

To do that you new to create `View` and extend `FrameLayout` and then override `onMeasure`.

```
public class SquareFramelayout extends Framelayout {  

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```